# Gearman problem when trying to run PHP cli

Tags: php, gnome-terminal

When I run the following command in terminal:

```
php somePHPfile.php
```

The following error happens:

```
PHP Warning:  PHP Startup: Unable to load dynamic library '/usr/lib/php5/20100525/gearman.so' - /usr/lib/php5/20100525/gearman.so: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory in Unknown on line 0
```

I've installed gearman and gearmanAdmin. The `gearman.so` is not present in the `/usr/lib/php/20100525/` path.

I've installed gearman from source. Gearman's version is 1.1.5 is installed.

I have on gearman.so in the following path:

```
/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libgearman.so.6.0.0
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this command:

```
sudo cp /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libgearman.so.6.0.0 /usr/lib/php/20100525/gearman.so
```

I know this is a rather crude way to do this. But, this should work well enough.

Comment: I ran it as root user:  cp: cannot create regular file `/usr/lib/php/20100525/gearman.so': No such file or directory

Comment: Then, `sudo mkdir /usr/lib/php/20100525/`

Comment: I have this directory dude. And I have some files in it

Comment: **Did you copy everything correctly**? And, are you sure that the `libgearman.so` file is in the place you say it is?

Comment: I have `libgearman.so.6.0.0` and directory is present.

Comment: Try `chmod 755 /usr/lib/php/20100525/` and try again.